# jQuery function .load() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, load, firebug

i have a problem. It's not the first time i use this jQuery function ( .load() ) that way, but now, i really can't understand why in this new web site, it's not working. In the Firebug Console, when i click on the link "connexion" the GET is in red and the 'form.login.php' is not loaded at all. Why?

ah by the way, on document ready, the loading of 'form.accueil.php' is working. But not the other .load call.

Here is a piece of my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function menuClick(tab)
    {

        switch (tab)
        {
            case -1: // accueil
                // alert(tab+':accueil');
                // $('#main_center').empty();
                $('#main_center').load('form.accueil.php');
                break;

            case 0: // connexion
                // alert(tab+':connexion');
                // $('#main_center').empty();
                $('#main_center').load('form.login.php');
                break;
        }   
    }

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#main_center').load('form.accueil.php');
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <?php
                    // Affichage du menu
                    echo '<li onClick="menuClick(-1);"><a class="" id="tab1" href="">Accueil</a></li>';

                    if (!$oLogin->get_connected())
                    {
                        // si pas connecté on affiche le module de connexion
                        echo '<li onClick="menuClick(0);"><a class="" id="tab2" href="">Connexion</a></li>';
                        // echo '<li onClick="menuClick(0);"><a class="" id="tab2" href="">Connexion</a></li>';
                        echo '<li onClick="menuClick(666);"><a class="" id="tab2" href="">Test</a></li>';
                    }
```

And here is 'form.login.php'

```
<form name="Identification" method="post" action="index.php">
    <table class="side-menu">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" id="th_conn">CONNEXION</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Nom d'utilisateur</td>
            <td><center><input class="text" type="text" name="usager"></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">Mot de passe</td>
            <td><center><input class="text" type="password" name="passwd"></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="submit" valign="top">
            <td></td>
            <td><center><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Soumettre"></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you expect `form.connexion.php` to load then the `load` call loads `form.login.php`?

Comment: oops my bad. I just changed it, i used the wrong term in my description.

Comment: without more information, my first guess is that form.login.php either doesn't exist or there is a error in the script you need to fix

Comment: form.login.php is a simple html form. Like you can see, i added the code.

Comment: if the AJAX call is coming back red then everything must be working as far as your javascript execution goes, the error must be with the file itself...can you load the file in the browser on its own properly? Also, the absolute path you give correct? or is form.login.php in a subfolder?

Comment: Yes i can load the file on its own in the browser and the path is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the ... it was missing the #. So even the jQuery script was unable to load the page.