# jQuery not working on load function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, load

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sneh_pandya/yvY7P/) which works perfectly.but when i use `load` function to render this form, `jquery` is not working.

Here is the code for load.(**`coffee script`**)

```
$(document.body).ready ->    
   $(".click").mouseenter ->
      $(".content-wrapper").load "emain #eform"
   return
return
```

The form shows perfectly but `jQuery` is missing.

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/emain" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-24 22:52:57 +0530
Processing by EmployeeController#emain as HTML
Emp Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "emps".* FROM "emps" WHERE "emps"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "
emps"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered employee/_form.html.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered employee/_content.html.erb (10.0ms)
Rendered employee/emain.html.erb within layouts/application (18.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 66ms (Views: 64.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-24 22:52:57 +0530
```

Comment: it mean that, when i render by `load function` only the page is displayed, as shown in `fiddle` page is displayed without js. done with indentation but no change.

Comment: Looking at it it's wrong because your indentation is wrong on here with your CoffeeScript.

Comment: done indentation..but then also no effect

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773255/jquery-function-load-doesnt-work?rq=1

Comment: Your fiddle is near unreadable. Pare it down. Also I didn't see `.load()` used. How is the fiddle in context to this question?

Comment: `load "emain #eform"` <- what is a `<emain>` tag? I think your query is missing a `#` or `.` that is a query right? Or is it a url path? I'm confused.